# The boundary of the object in an image changes when we rotate the image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rotation, boundary

I have used matlab Code of imrotate with 'crop' option to rotate an image. The image is rotated but the boundary count of the object pixels in the image changes. Why is it so? Is there any option to retain the boundary pixel count even after the rotation?

I also tried out using rotation matrix for the object rotation. But same situation occurs?
Can someone help to resolve this?

```
Irot_new =imread('square.bmp');
Irot = imrotate(Irot_new,-i,'bicubic','crop');
Irot_rgb = rgb2gray(Irot);
BW = imbinarize(Irot_rgb );
 B = bwboundaries(BW);
 boundary = B{1}; 
 x = boundary(:,2);
 y = boundary(:,1);
 boundary_size = size(boundary)
```

[image]

Comment: When you rotate an image the pixel coordinates are mapped to another pairs of coordinates but those new values are not necessarely integer. This problem is called aliasing. You can not preserve the shape AND the number of displayed pixels since a raster image is not a coutinuous space.

Comment: Also are you trying to rotate your image by an angle `i` aka the imaginary unit ?

Comment: Yeah i am trying to rotate the image by an angle i (0 to 180) at 10 degree difference. I copied the portion of the code in the for loop.That s why it is 'i'.. not imaginary unit!

Comment: @obchardon Aliasing part i understood.. But i got boundaries almost correct near 0 degree (boundary size is 1068), 10 degree (1032), 30 degree(966) ,40 degree(872) 50 degree(878) 60(976) 70 degree(1034) 80 degree(1075)90 degree(1078).  Can you kindly clarify why such a gradation occurs for the 30 -60 degrees? Will such a large gradation occurs for those angles too?

Comment: After you have inserted the object, you can change it in many ways. To rotate the image/shape, click and drag on the circle at the top.